# Как сделать точный таймер?

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь разобраться с таймером в C#. Все работает! Но интервал таймера не точный, то есть болтается(то разница 6 сек то 10). Использовал System.Timers.Timer

Comment: используйте [другой таймер](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: уже использовал TimerCallback. Есть другой вариант?

Comment: А как вы используете его? можно код?

Comment: Windows не является операционной системой реального времени. Поэтому идеально точный таймер не сделать никак. Вопрос в том, какая именно точность вам нужна?

Comment: все разобрался, спасибо)